# "Invalid Operation" error when trying to using OpenGL in GTK in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to embed my OpenGL application in GTK but I can't get this simple example to work. I'm using example from [this place](https://athenajc.gitbooks.io/python-gtk-3-api/content/gtk-group/gtkglarea.html#geterror). My code:

```py
class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        area = Gtk.GLArea()
        self.add(area)

        area.connect('render', self.on_render)

    def on_render(self, area, context):
        glViewport(0, 0, 100, 100)

        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        try:
            glColor3f(0, 0, 0)
        except Error as err:
            print("Error: {0}".format(err))  # invalid operation
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
        try:
            glEnd()
        except Error as err:
            print("Error: {0}".format(err))  # invalid operation

        return True


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I'm getting error 1282 "invalid operation" on lines with "glColor3f" and "glEnd", any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The example you linked is wrong, and should not be used. There's a whole example for C developers available here: https://github.com/ebassi/glarea-example

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated GL1/GL2 API, like `glBegin` and `glVertex`, but GTK will create a GL 3.2+ context, which does not have that API.

You can use deprecated GL API only on legacy GL contexts; GTK will fall back to legacy contexts if your GL driver does not support modern, non-deprecated GL contexts. You can check if the GL context is a legacy one by using [`Gdk.GLContext.is_legacy()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/classes/GLContext.html#Gdk.GLContext.is_legacy) method.

In general, you should not use pre-GL 3.2 API to begin with. If you want to create a triangle in GL, you will have to use vertex buffers and GLSL shaders.